# React Hook useMemo has missing dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How to handle this warning? (React Hook useMemo has missing dependencies: 'deleteTutorial' and 'openTutorial'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)
If I put openTutorial and deleteTutorial inside useMemo hook, there wont be compile warning, but then I have a problem that those two functions wont work.

```
  const openTutorial = (rowIndex) => {
    const id = tutorialsRef.current[rowIndex].id;

    props.history.push("/tutorials/" + id);
  };

  const deleteTutorial = (rowIndex) => {
    const id = tutorialsRef.current[rowIndex].id;

    TutorialDataService.remove(id).then((response) => {
      props.history.push("/tutorials");

      let newTutorials = [...tutorialsRef.current];
      newTutorials.splice(rowIndex, 1);

      setTutorials(newTutorials);
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  };

  const columns = useMemo(() => [
    {
      Header: "Naziv",
      accessor: "title"
    }, {
      Header: "Opis",
      accessor: "description"
    }, {
      Header: "Površina",
      accessor: "povrsina"
    }, {
      Header: "Dužina x Širina",
      accessor: properties => properties.duzina + ' x ' + properties.sirina
    }, {
      Header: "",
      accessor: "actions",
      Cell: (props) => {
        const rowIdx = props.row.id;

        return (<div>
          <span onClick={() => openTutorial(rowIdx)}>
            <i className="far fa-edit action mr-2"></i>
          </span>

          <span onClick={() => (confirmDialog('Da li želite obrisati parcelu?', () => deleteTutorial(rowIdx)))
}>
            <i className="fas fa-trash action"></i>
          </span>

        </div>);
      }
    }
  ], []);
```

/*EDIT*/
Now I have problem that useCallback has missing dependency props.history. Is it ok to fix it like this:

```
const callHistory = useCallback(() => {
    props.history.push("/tutorials");
  }, [props.history]);

  const deleteTutorial = useCallback((rowIndex) => {
    const id = tutorialsRef.current[rowIndex].id;

    TutorialDataService.remove(id).then((response) => {

      callHistory();
      let newTutorials = [...tutorialsRef.current];
      newTutorials.splice(rowIndex, 1);

      setTutorials(newTutorials);
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  }, [callHistory]);
```

Comment: what does mean "functions does not work"? is "deleteTutorial()" called with wrong data or is not called at all? did you set breakpoint inside to check what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain, when I make it like this:

```
  const openTutorial = useCallback((rowIndex) => {
    const id = tutorialsRef.current[rowIndex].id;

    props.history.push("/tutorials/" + id);
  }, []);

  const deleteTutorial = useCallback((rowIndex) => {
    const id = tutorialsRef.current[rowIndex].id;

    TutorialDataService.remove(id).then((response) => {
      props.history.push("/tutorials");

      let newTutorials = [...tutorialsRef.current];
      newTutorials.splice(rowIndex, 1);

      setTutorials(newTutorials);
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  }, []);

  const columns = useMemo(() => [
    {
      Header: "Naziv",
      accessor: "title"
    }, {
      Header: "Opis",
      accessor: "description"
    }, {
      Header: "Površina",
      accessor: "povrsina"
    }, {
      Header: "Dužina x Širina",
      accessor: properties => properties.duzina + ' x ' + properties.sirina
    }, {
      Header: "",
      accessor: "actions",
      Cell: (props) => {
        const rowIdx = props.row.id;

        return (<div>
          <span onClick={() => openTutorial(rowIdx)}>
            <i className="far fa-edit action mr-2"></i>
          </span>

          <span onClick={() => (confirmDialog('Da li želite obrisati parcelu?', () => deleteTutorial(rowIdx)))
}>
            <i className="fas fa-trash action"></i>
          </span>

        </div>);
      }
    }
  ], [deleteTutorial, openTutorial]);
```

i get this warning:
*React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'props.history'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps*

So I am wondering if it is ok to put props.history in dependency:

```
  const openTutorial = useCallback((rowIndex) => {
    const id = tutorialsRef.current[rowIndex].id;

    props.history.push("/tutorials/" + id);
  }, [props.history]);
```

@moderator: sorry, I dont know how to put code in comment, so I answered my question, but I think this is really answer to my question :)